Glue suggestion for refrigerator door gasket
As you can see from the following picture, the gasket of my refrigerator door  is coming off. Could anyone suggest a glue to fix it?
I tried to find glues on Amazon. I am overwhelmed by the options.
TIA for your response.


In my admittedly limited experience, refrigerator gaskets are pressure-fit and when they start falling out it is because they are worn out and need to be replaced. Make/model of refrigerator?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, FGHC2331PFAA Frigidaire Refrigerator

Your photo leaves something to be desired. Do I see a barbed tab that fits into a slot?

are you certain that the old one is glued?

My experience is also limited, but AFAIK the gasket is typically a press-fit, shaped to be retained in place by flanges/channels on the gasket itself and/or the door.  Search some videos on the internet on how to install refrigerator gaskets.
